# Using mysqli affected rows in object oriented style function - not returning expected result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to improve my functions include file for a site I'm making. The code below is an extract of the functions include. I'm trying to get get affected_rows to check that the query has been successfully executed but no luck.

```
<?php
function connect() {
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
                . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    return $mysqli;

}

function insert($type, $values) {
    $mysqli = connect();

    if ( $type == 'newclient' ) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO client_details (first_name, surname, email, password, dob, country, region, postcode, phone_main, phone_mobile, date_registered, regcode) values ( '{$_SESSION['first_name']}', '{$_SESSION['surname']}', '{$_SESSION['confirm_email']}', '$scrambledeggs', '{$_SESSION['dob']}', '{$_SESSION['country']}', '{$_SESSION['region']}', '{$_SESSION['postcode']}', '{$_SESSION['phone_main']}', '{$_SESSION['phone_mobile']}', NOW(), '$verification_hash')";

        if ( !$mysqli->query($query) ) {
        return "Errormessage: $mysqli->error";  
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get affected rows in order to confirm the query has run correctly, but my attempts so far haven't worked, this is what I had tried...

```
if ( !$mysqli->query($query) ) {
    return "Errormessage: $mysqli->error";  
}
if (($mysqli->affected_rows) > 0 ) {
    ($_SESSION['success'] = 1);
}
```

Comment: Tried using `var_dump($mysqli->affected_rows)` ?

Comment: @Jari - thanks I have looked at var_dump but again can't get it to work, would you be able to suggest where in the code it would go? I had some help with this script from someone else suggesting this layout would be a good way to nest MySQL queries in a separate include file but am still struggling with sending any indication of the success of the query back to the page that is calling it.

Comment: is record actually added into table?